# Huge HTML table - filter rows containing a string

Tags: python, html, performance, html-parsing

I have sample HTML document as shown below. Now I need to filter all the rows with Profession as Engineer(column2) and generate resultant HTML document. But the problem here is that my document contains 2 million rows and size of the document is 1GB. Could anyone please suggest a faster way to process this?

I tried parsing using Python and BeautifulSoup module and tried to filter but it is taking more than 15 hours to process the data.. Is there a faster way to do this?

Code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
fd = open("input.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(fd.read())
for tr in soup('tr'):
    if str(tr('td')[1].text) != "Engineer":
         tr.extract()
with open("output.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
fd.close()
```

INPUT:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Profession</td>
    <td>Address</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Assassin</td>
    <td>JohnWick</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tony</td>
    <td>Engineer</td>
    <td>IronMan</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Stark</td>
    <td>Engineer</td>
    <td>IronMan</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Bruce</td>
    <td>Professor</td>
    <td>Hulk</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Profession</td>
    <td>Address</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tony</td>
    <td>Engineer</td>
    <td>IronMan</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Stark</td>
    <td>Engineer</td>
    <td>IronMan</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No idea bud, seems like a reasonable question to me!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to retain the whitespace / formatting? Is this something you need to do many times, or just as a one off?

If it's a one-time job, you might be able to do it a little more simply. Try opening it up in Notepad++, Sublime etc. Use find and replace to reformat so you have one code row per table row:

```
<tr><td>Bruce</td><td>Professor</td><td>Hulk</td></tr>
<tr><td>Stark</td><td>Engineer</td><td>IronMan</td></tr>
```

(You can do it without this step, but it'll make it easier to see what's going on).

Then you could find and replace for:

```
<tr>.*?<td>Professor</td>.*?</tr>
```

with a blank row (repeat for each non-Engineer role). If there are a lot of professions, you can use back-references to change the Engineer rows from

```
<tr> content </tr>
```

to

```
<tr-keep> content </tr>
```

and then find and replace all of the vanilla tr rows.

You could also open it up in Excel and filter that way. I'm sure there are some good Python solutions here too, just telling you how I'd do it - I've had similar issues handling large files in Python, and you can do a lot of data munging in a basic text or spreadsheet editor. Excel eats a million rows for breakfast.

Comment: Thank You Very Much @penitent_tangent. This simple idea really helped. Though I was not able to do this with excel or notepad++ as they were crashing, I was able to apply this idea in vim editor and achieved the desired result in 5 mins. This thought really helped a lot. Thank You.

Comment: Though this already solved my problem will keep this post open to see, if any interested users will suggest a programmatic approach too.